# How to find the angle of a force applied to a point in the interior of a disk so that is at equilibrium?

Tags: vectors, euclidean-geometry, physics, classical-mechanics

I'm trying to find a way to this problem using euclidean geometry. Is that possible?.

The problem is as follows:

> The figure from below shows a pulley whose has an axis in its center.
> A wire is rolled to the pulley so that one end has a mass of $4\,kg$
> hanging from it. In another place situated in the interior of the disk
> a pin is attached to a thin rope of negligible weight from where a
> person can pull the rope. Find the angle $\theta$ so that the pulley
> is at equilibrium when the force applied to the point where the rope
> is fixed is equal to $70\,N$. Assume that the acceleration due gravity
> is ($g=10\,\frac{m}{s^2}$). Hint: You may use the approximation of
> $\cos 16^{\circ}=\frac{24}{25}$.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&37^{\circ}\\
2.&53^{\circ}\\
3.&16^{\circ}\\
4.&74^{\circ}\\
5.&45^{\circ}\\
\end{array}$

Does it exist a way to solve this geometrically?. I've tried to describe the approach which I've attempted to solve this problem. This is summarized in the figure from below.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

Typically it seems easy to spot how to apply torques in am object when is straight as an arrow or its shape is linear, but how to do this when the object has a circular shape?. Can someone help me with this?.

**I've tried all sorts of constructions to find the radius ($r_{1}$) which is indicated in the figure from above. But I couldn't. Does it exist a way to relate it with what it is being asked without the necessity of using vector decomposition?.**

**I'm not sure if the line which crosses to the force is tangent. Does it exist a way to tell if its placed in the right spot?. What would be the maximum angle so that the tangent is situated in those $40\,cm$?. Is it related with the $45^{\circ}$?.**

I think if its less than $45^{\circ}$ the line crosses the force below the horizontal line in the disk but if the angle is greater than those $45^{\circ}$ then it will be over the horizontal line. Can someone help me with that part as well?.

Comment: The fundamental statics theorem says that in such a case, equilibrium is achieved when the torques have same intensity and are opposite.

Answer (score 1):

> Typically it seems easy to spot how to apply torques in am object when is straight as an arrow or its shape is linear, but how to do this when the object has a circular shape?. Can someone help me with this?.

$\text{Torque} = F_{t}\cdot r$ where $F_t$ is the force tangential to the angle of the circle at point where the force acts.

As a start, I find it hard to understand how this problem should be solved. To reach the equilibrium, you must first compute how much the resulting tangential force should be. to compute the angle from the force on the rope and its tangential force, it is simply required to decompose the vector into a relative tangential and normal component. Either way, i will continue with what I got:
The resulting tangential force required to reach an equilibrium can be derived from the following equation: $F_tr_2 = mgR = 2800$

First compute the radius $r_2$ between the rope and the center. The vertical part is already given, and the horizontal part can be deduced from the 45 degree angle and the remaining height using the radius (70-40 = 30). As such, the radius equals 50. Therefore $F_t = 56N$
Additionally, $F_t$ is the tangential part of F, with respect to the angle to the center of the disk:
$$F_t = F\sin(\theta + \alpha)$$
$\alpha$ is the angle between the line connecting the center and the connecting point on the rope and the vertical axis. this is equal to $\arctan(30/40)$, but that is irrelevant for the solution. Knowing F=70N, the equation can be solved as follows:
$$\sin(\theta + \alpha) = 0.8$$
$$\sin\theta \cos\alpha + \cos\theta \sin\alpha = 0.8$$
$$5\sin\theta \cos\alpha + 5\cos\theta \sin\alpha = 4$$
Since we know $\alpha$ is part of that satisfying 3-4-5 triangle, we can rule $\alpha$ out of the equation:
$$4\sin\theta + 3\cos\theta = 4$$
$$(4\sin\theta)^2 = (4 - 3\cos\theta)^2$$
$$16\sin^2\theta = 9\cos^2\theta -24\cos\theta + 16$$
$$16-16\cos^2\theta = 9\cos^2\theta -24\cos\theta + 16$$
$$0 = 25\cos^2\theta -24\cos\theta$$
and from here it can be easily seen that $\cos\theta = 0$ or $\cos\theta = \frac{24}{25}$
So that immediately explains why that hint is given and might solve your question to what is the maximum angle. This angle is namely where $\cos\theta = 0$ thus 90 degrees.
Maybe this doesnt answer your question to the fullest, but maybe it helps a bit.

Comment: Tip: use a backslash in front of trig functions for proper Roman-letter formatting.

Comment: @Petrus1904 Can you please explain, **what would happen if the angle $\alpha$ is less acute and more obtuse?. Is there a limit for $\alpha$ so that the sine function to be positive?.** Otherwise it would be negative. I'm assuming that the rationale you used is that $\tau=rF\sin(\theta+\alpha)$ and the sine function is due that is the vertical component of the force. But I wonder **why**  haven't you thought $180-(\alpha+\theta)$. Other than just looking at the drawing it just seems to imply that the angle $\theta$ is acute. Can you attend this question please?.

Comment: @Petrus1904 Can you attend my question from above please?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell I wonder if there is any limit to both angles. What I can deduce from my answer is that for any $\alpha$ find a $\theta$ such that their sum is either (roughly) 127 degrees or 53 degrees or any full rotation further from the vertical axis. So even if $\alpha$ is larger than 127 degrees, both solutions for $\theta$ become negative (or a full rotation further from this negative value). Why I havent wondered about using $\sin(180-\alpha-\theta) $ is that is equal to $\sin(\alpha+\theta)$ and I like to keep my notations short.

Comment: The essential facts are that the pin is $50$ cm from the axis and the line of action of the rope needs to be $40$ cm from the axis. There are two lines through the pin whose distance to the axis is $40$ cm. One is horizontal, the other is $16$ degrees clockwise from vertical. Since this is a multiple choice question and $90$ is not offered as an answer, choose $16.$

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to look at this problem. The rectangle in the first figure has height $40$ cm and base $30$ cm. So its diagonal, which is $r_1$, is $50$ cm. The angle $\alpha$ between $r_1$ and the vertical line traced from the point where the rope is fixed is  $\arctan 30/40\approx 0.64$ rad, corresponding to about $37°$. Note that $\sin \alpha=3/5$ and $\cos \alpha=4/5$.

Now note that the effect of our pulling force on the $4$-Kg mass is proportional to $\sin(\alpha+\theta)$: it is maximal if $\theta=\pi/2-\alpha=90°-37°=53°$ (this is the case in which we pull the rope perpendicularly to $r_1$), and reduces to zero if $\theta=-\alpha=-37°$ (this is the theoretical case in which we pull the rope in a direction coinciding with $r_1$).

So, considering that the effect of the pulling force on the $4$-Kg mass is further reduced by a factor equal to $r_1/r=50/70=5/7$, we have to find $\theta $ such that

$$70\cdot \frac 57\, \sin(\alpha+\theta)=40$$

which gives

$$\sin(\alpha+\theta)=\frac 45$$

To solve it, we remind that

$$\sin(a+b)=\sin a \cos b +\cos a \sin b$$

and then

$$\sin \alpha \cos\theta +\cos \alpha \sin \theta =\frac 45$$

$$\frac 35 \cos\theta + \frac 45 \sin \theta=\frac 45$$

$$3 \cos\theta + 4 \sqrt{1-\cos^2 \theta}  = 5$$

Solving the quadratic for $\cos\theta$ we get

$$\cos \theta =\frac{24}{25}$$

and then, using the hint

$$\theta=16°$$

Comment: Can you add a drawing so I can see where's exactly the angle $\alpha$?. Is it possible to solve the problem without knowing the angle $45^{\circ}$?. In my attempt to solve the problem I situated a straight arm making a tangential point with the spot where the rope is attached in the disk. But is that correct?. I understand that the logic you use is that for the torque to be **maximum** $r_{1}$ must be perpendicular with $F$ is that correct?. The rest I'm following you that for that to happen the value from the sine function must be $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and the rest takes from there.

Comment: It would really help a lot if you could include a drawing to your answer. From it I think it reassures that $\alpha$ is complementary to $\theta$ and my guess to put the $\frac{\pi}{2}$ was right. But that was the source of my confusion. what if $\theta$ would had been greater than $45^{\circ}$ or some angle which would had caused contradiction in the quadratic equation?. I'm not good with picturing scenarios mentally but I think it wouldn't matter at the end, $\alpha$ would still lie in the vertical isn't it?. Can you include drawing for this part?.

Comment: Perhaps can you attend my questions from above please?. I'm confused more specifically what if $\theta$ isn't that acute and is more obtuse. Wouldn't it meant that $180-(\alpha+\theta)$ and you might use $\sin(180-(\alpha+\theta))$ would this be the rationale?.